# Restful api request.delete not deleting requested item

Tags: python, python-requests, flask-restful, http-delete

Trying to use requests.delete to remove an entry from an api server database but I cannot seem to get it to remove the entry.
The functions on the front end:

```
@app.route("/delete/<item>", methods=['DELETE', 'GET'])
def delete_entry(item):
    resp = requests.delete("URL/delete/<item>")
    resp = resp.json()
    return render_template('index.html', list=resp)

Api server function:
@app.route("/delete/<item>, methods=['DELETE', 'GET'])
def delete_entry(item):
    db = get_db()
    db.execute("DELETE FROM entries WHERE what_to_do='"+item+"'")
    db.commit()
    return get_items()
```

The api server says:

```
"DELETE /delete/%3Citem%3E HTTP/1.1" 200
```

The front end says:

```
"GET /delete/hw3 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But the item does not get deleted and im not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app method do not use the item parameter, should be:

```
@app.route("/delete/<item>", methods=['DELETE', 'GET'])
def delete_entry(item):
    resp = requests.delete("URL/delete/%s" % item)
    resp = resp.json()
    return render_template('index.html', list=resp)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution to my issue!